# Mule Anypoint Gateway for .NET platform not running as a service in windows 7 professional desktop

Tags: windows, mule, msmq, mule-studio, msmqintegrationbinding

I am trying to use MSMQ queue inside Mule flow;Going by the docs [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/MSMQ+Connector), I find we need to run Anypoint Gateway as a service. The service wont run and gives error:

```
"Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"
```

System:windows 7 professional desktop 64 bit;
How to resolve the issue?

Info from System logs:

```
A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the Anypoint Gateway service to connect.
```

Info from Application logs:

```
The program AnyPoint-Gateway-Service.exe version 1.0.0.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
```

Error from MSI installer:

```
Product: Anypoint Gateway for Windows -- Error 1920. Service 'Anypoint Gateway' (MuleMSMQService) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.
```

I have admin privileges to install any service and running on .NET 4.03 platform.

Comment: What does the Windows event log show for this application? The above error alone can't allow anyone to help figure out a possible solution.

Comment: I have edited the question for further info.Thanks David for looking into this issue.Having hard time with MSMQ mule flow!

Comment: Hi David. I resolved the issue now by updating to .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mule Doc says for a .NET 4.0 prerequisite.
But I resolved the above error by:
1.Updating to .NET 4.5 platform
2.Running the Anypoint-Gateway.exe as compatible for windows 7(tweaking the properties of exe).
3.Also check if you have admin rights.